# Explanation of script defer attribute

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How exactly does <script defer=“defer”> work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work)

Can anybody explain me how **defer** works?

As example how following code will work:

`document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer " + ((location.protocol == "https:") ? "src='javascript:void(0)'" : "src=//0") + "><\/script>")`

And why using different value of **src** for different protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defer` is an IE attribute that tells the browser to delay the execution of the script.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1

"When set, this boolean attribute provides a hint to the user agent that the script is not going to generate any document content (e.g., no "document.write" in javascript) and thus, the user agent can continue parsing and rendering."

Comment: So in other words... stay away from it? :)

Comment: @JeffreySweeney: Quite the opposite, are you writing code with document.writes?

Comment: Well, if the W3C's ok with it... 'IE only' makes me cringe.

Comment: If you don't need the script before the page has loaded, then there is no problem with using defer. Defer allows the content of your page to be loaded before scripts start executing. Of course there are ways of delaying script execution using JavaScript, such as `window.onload` or jQuery's `$(document).ready(function(){})`