# Is script defer reliable?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I serve all javascripts combined in one large file via Amazon Cloudfront. But since jQuery is so large, I'm thinking about using the version provided by Google. Of course I would include both script tags in the bottom of the page and would add the defer attribute, if I had not read this article: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/defer/

If I understand it right, the defer attribute works only in the Firefox correctly, while every other browser (at that time) would execute the scripts in a random order. Is that true? Of course my scripts depend on jQuery, so it must be executed before my scripts.

Comment: Interesting. I've never heard that it only works in Fx, au contraire. PPK suggests that `defer` works differently in IE4+ and older browsers, but does not mention that it doesn't work in other browsers. His article might be a bit old, though ...

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html

Comment: There are a lot of good ressources linked in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work

Comment: Why do you need `defer` in the first place? You place all files at the bottom on your page and you should always use jQuery via `$( function () { /* ... your code .. */ });`, so no problem there..

Answer (score 1):

In 2017, it seems reliable enough to stop avoiding these 5 letters in favor of 17-liner workarounds. Browser support for `defer` is [quite good these days](https://caniuse.com/#search=defer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'd bother with defer if you aren't certain of its support. Just do this instead:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js"></script>  
<script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='localJSFolder/jquery-1.6.4.min.js'></script>")</script>
```

All modern browsers ought to run the scripts sequentially. This is the easiest way to use Google's CDN with a local fallback.

Comment: Please note, that you might have problems with </script> inside your script body embedded in your html code. it's recommended to escape it as <\/script>.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this (using window.onload to truly behave like defer):

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    if (script.readyState) { // IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                // do something
            }   
        };  
    }   
    else { // Others
        script.onload = function() {
            // do something (the same thing as above)
        };  
    }   
    script.src = file;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
});
```

If you need more than one file, put in a loop and set file to something like file[x]