# Can I tell jQuery not to wait for extern scripts, and images to trigger all-loaded function?

Tags: jquery

I have the problem that I don't want to wait for extern scripts before my jquery load-function is triggered.

Can I do something against it?

code of load function:

```
$(function(){ 
//    ... code here
});
```

**UPDATE**

Well defer works very well to ensure the functionality of my scripts.
 But now I have huge Problems with the extern scripts functionality.

i.e. this twitter box does not load anymore

```
        <script type="text/javasript" charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js" defer="defer"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
        new TWTR.Widget({
          version: 2,
          type: 'profile',
          rpp: 4,
          interval: 30000,
          width: 275,
          height: 247,
          theme: {
            shell: {
              background: '#8ec1da',
              color: '#ffffff'
            },
            tweets: {
              background: '#ffffff',
              color: '#444444',
              links: '#1985b5'
            }
          },
          features: {
            scrollbar: true,
            loop: false,
            live: true,
            behavior: 'all'
          }
        }).render().setUser('xxxxxxxx').start();
        </script>
```

as well facebook connect has problems, like Buttons in chrome do not work any more, and so on ...

Comment: Show code snippet where you use load function

Comment: How about including those scripts after jQuery load functions. However it would throw an error in many cases.

Comment: can I load js scripts within that function via JS with jQuery? And would this be a solution?

Comment: You should consider post this Update as a new question to get more reponses...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid blocking the page rendering while downloading an external script file use `defer` attribute.

Xhtml sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="external/dont-wait-for-me.js"></script>
```

More info: [How exactly does <script defer="defer"> work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work)

Also, you can load the script files dynamically from Jquery using `getScript`:

```
$(function(){ 
    //Do stuff first
    //...
    //Then...
    $.getScript('external/load-me-after-the-dom-is-ready.js', function() {
       alert("the js is loaded");
    });
});
```