# Calculate Subtotal Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, append, calculator

I'm trying to get the subtotal of items that the user appends to the shopping cart, but can't seem to get it to work.

Basically I have a list of items, on which they have an add to cart button which is linked to a jquery function that appends some html to the shopping cart:

```
$('#object01').click(function(){
    if ($('#slideShoppingCart').is(":hidden")) {
    $('#slideShoppingCart').slideToggle(500);   
    $('#objectList').append('<div class="shoppingCartObject"><img src="img/leather-backpack-cart.jpg" width="75" height="75"><div class="cartObjectInfo"><h1 class="cartTitle">Gentleman&#39;s Satchel</h1><div class="closeCartObject">x</div><h2 class="cartDescription">Chestnut Leather</h2><h3 class="quantity">QTY. 1</h3><h3 class="cartPrice">£<span class="price">300</span></h3></div></div>')
    } else {
        $('#objectList').append('<div class="shoppingCartObject"><img src="img/leather-backpack-cart.jpg" width="75" height="75"><div class="cartObjectInfo"><h1 class="cartTitle">Gentleman&#39;s Satchel</h1><div class="closeCartObject">x</div><h2 class="cartDescription">Chestnut Leather</h2><h3 class="quantity">QTY. 1</h3><h3        class="cartPrice">£<span class="price">300</span></h3></div></div>')
    }
    });
    $('.closeCartObject').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();

    return false;
});
```

In which I have the price wrapped in a span with a class called price.
I then have a span in my shopping cart with an id of total.

I have this function to calculate the price, which doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function getTotal(){
var total = 0;
$('.price').each(function(){
    total += parseFloat(this.innerHTML)
});
$('#total').text(total);
getTotal();
});
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't seem to work".

Comment: On chrome the total stays at 0, on firefox there is simple no digit in the #total span

Comment: What happens when you run your code with Chrome's developer tools on show? Do you get errors?

Comment: on firebug there is no error, on chrome I seem to get this; which i'm not sure what it means.

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: *Maximum call stack size exceeded*, it sounds possible that you have inadvertent recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Your function:

```
$(document).ready(function getTotal(){
var total = 0;
$('.price').each(function(){
    total += parseFloat(this.innerHTML)
});
$('#total').text(total);
getTotal();
});
```

contains a call to getTotal() from getTotal(). You have inadvertent **recursion**.

EDIT:
OK, try this: (it'd be easier if there was a jsfiddle for your code though)

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var total = 0;
    $('.price').each(function()
    {
        total += parseFloat(this.innerHTML)
    });

    $('#total').text(total);
});
```

Comment: how exactly do I fix this, sorry i'm not too sure what that means. I'm still fairly new to jquery

Comment: Well, why are you calling getTotal() at the end of your function?

Comment: good point, but whether its there or not doesn't seem to make a difference :/

Comment: That seems to have the same effect, I'm assuming the problem is that the cart starts out empty, which gives it the total of 0.

Comment: yes, at first. but if the user adds an object to the cart, the price needs to go up accordingly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19608/discussion-between-maxim-siebert-and-lee-taylor)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your calculation logic works

```
var total = 0;
$('.price').each(function(){
    total += parseFloat(this.innerHTML)
});
```

But the problem is that you are calling the "getTotal()" function inside itself.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var getTotal = function(){
  var total = 0;
  $('.price').each(function(){
      total += parseFloat(this.innerHTML);
  });
  return total;
}  

$('#total').text(getTotal());

});
```

Comment: For some reason that still doesn't seem to work. :/ I think it has something to do with the shopping cart being empty, which calculates to 0

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your JS in `<script defer="defer">` tag, this means it gets run last - its possible your function tries to caclulate before the Dom is totoally finished (this may have only been with earlier version of jQuery though)

Alternatively add a setTimeout to call your sub-total function after a few seconds.

You may also want to add some alerts to your function, make sure the fields its trying to target aere targeted correctly.

Defer: [How exactly does <script defer="defer"> work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work)

setTimeout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout