# Defer Attribute No Src Nothing Inside

Tags: javascript, html, moodle, script-tag, deferred-rendering

What happens when there is a `script` tag with a `defer` attribute, no `src` or `async` attribute, and nothing inside it, as in:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
```

As far as I understand it, `defer` simply tells the page it can keep rendering while this `script` tag loads; the spec says it should be used when the tag has an `src` attribute, not when it has JavaScript inside it, but what about when it has nothing inside it AND no `src` attribute? Why would someone want that?

This is from my school. It is on a Moodle page, version 1, not sure of minor version, so the page would be huge & change a lot based on who's logged in, etc.; please tell me what other source code you need to answer the question.

**EDIT**
I wasn't very clear on what I'm asking. I know what happens in this situation, but I'm asking WHY someone would want it to happen this way. It seems useless to have a `defer` attribute with no JavaScript code to defer, so I'm wondering whether there are some side effects a website designer (circa 5-10 years ago) could use.

Comment: All the details are [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-defer).

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work

Comment: I saw all those, but they only say what happens. I suppose I'm asking why someone would want a situation like this. I will edit my question to make that clearer.

Comment: @trysis: I can't think of any reason for that script block at all.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this, but what if there is an `src`attribute on some pages, but not others? I will make this an answer, then if no one can think of a better answer, accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Moodle is a big site, with many pages, it is possible that `defer` attribute is useful on some pages, but they put it on all the pages, even ones that don't need it. Other than that, I can not think of a reason for it.

Comment: As no one else has provided an answer, I gave the closest answer I could think of. If anyone can provide a better answer, I'm all ears.