# Html & defer attribute

Tags: javascript

Having the code below:

```
<html>
    <head>  

        <script>            
            function elem_onload() {
                console.log("elem_onload");
            };      
        </script>

    </head>

    <body onload="elem_onload()">       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>      
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
console.log("external script");
```

the defer attribute doesn't seems to work. The output is:

```
external script
elem_onload
```

whether with or without defer attribute. Shoudn't it be

```
elem_onload
external script
```

with defer defined?

## Duplicated answer!?

I'd like to state that my answer isn't duplicate of

[How exactly does <script defer=“defer”> work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work)

The referenced recommended answer is about inline script where the browser behavior is clear for me - it simply ignores `defer`. My question is about external script in which case the browser should execute the external deferred script

> after the document has been parsed

as documentation states hence after `onload` event.

**So I'm waiting for an appropriate answer...**

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work

Comment: Haven't used defer before, but shouldn't a value be assigned to the property, e.g. `defer="true"` ?

Comment: You are right that it seems counter intuitive, but you've not said what browser you are using for this, whether you have got the same behaviour in different browser nor whether any of content is cacheable.

Answer (score 1):

It is about the `onload`.
Here's a definition of `onload` attribute, taken from [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp).

> The onload attribute fires when an object has been loaded.
>
> onload is most often used within the <body> element to execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.). However, it can be used on other elements as well (see "Supported HTML tags" below).

Hence, the `onload` function will execute **after** the content inside the body had been loaded, that is - after the inner script had executed.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that *remdevtec* answer isn't correct as he seemed to forget that I used `defer` attribute in the script tag while the definition says:

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script
>   is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed

So in such a case (at least in my opinion) external script should be executed after `onload`, but it is not.

Comment: According to MDN: "This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded."