# Defer attribute and onload event

Tags: javascript

Having the code below:

```
<html>
    <head>  

        <script>            
            function elem_onload() {
                console.log("elem_onload");
            };      
        </script>

    </head>

    <body onload="elem_onload()">       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>      
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
console.log("external script");
```

the defer attribute doesn't seems to work. The output is:

```
external script
elem_onload
```

whether with or without defer attribute. Shoudn't it be

```
elem_onload
external script
```

with defer defined?

## Duplicated answer!?

I'd like to state that my answer isn't duplicate of

[How exactly does <script defer=“defer”> work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work)

The referenced recommended answer is about inline script where the browser behavior is clear for me - it simply ignores `defer`. My question is about external script in which case the browser should execute the external deferred script

> after the document has been parsed

as documentation states hence after `onload` event.

**So I'm waiting for an appropriate answer...**

Comment: [4.21.1 Script element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-defer): "There are three possible modes that can be selected using these attributes. If the async attribute is present, then the script will be executed as soon as it is available, but without blocking further parsing of the page. **If the async attribute is not present but the defer attribute is present, then the script is executed when the page has finished parsing**. If neither attribute is present, then the script is fetched and executed immediately, before the user agent continues parsing the page"

Comment: So You suggest that "onload" event is always triggered when the page has been parsed and therefore after deferred script?

Comment: Try setting `type` and `src` of `<script type=""></script>` at close of `elem_onload`

Comment: [`12.2.6 The end`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-end): Step 3. Execute all deferred scripts; Step 4. Fire `DOMContentLoaded`; ... Step 7: Fire `load` event

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The external script deferred by the `defer` attribute is executed before the ([`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)) is fired, i.e. when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed. The `onLoad` attribute on a `<body>` tag, on the other hand, fires only when a web page is fully loaded.

Therefore, the defer attribute is indeed working. You may test it by trying the two cases below. In both cases the content of **script.js** file should be this:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('sample').innerHTML);
```

**CASE 1 HTML** - with `defer` --> logs "Sample text"

```
<body onLoad="elem_onload()">       
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>    
<div id="sample">Sample text</div>
</body>
```

**CASE 2 HTML** - without `defer` --> logs an error

```
<body onLoad="elem_onload()">       
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>    
<div id="sample">Sample text</div>
</body>
```

Comment: They are executed **before** `DOMContentLoaded` is fired

Comment: The order is defined here -> [`12.2.6 The end`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-end)

Answer (score -2):

Thx. all for help.

So the statement "...after the document has been parsed" from original doc. ([MDN <script> tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script))
refers say step #0 from [12.2.6 The end](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-end)

when document is completely parsed and now there are several tasks to be done on that occasion. Those tasks includes running external deferred scripts which
is prior (#3) to `onload` event.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes. The load event fires at step #7.