# Is DOMContentLoaded fired after downloading all script tags?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

Consider the following scenario:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="js/heavy_js_file.js" defer></script>
    <script src="js/heavy_js_file2.js" defer></script>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Would `DOMContentLoaded` fire after downloading and executing all external deferred scripts?

P.S: [MDN definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) says `DOMContentLoaded` is fired after parsing the html DOM. I am not sure if parsing the html dom means downloading and executing js files as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as far as your script is not async, DOMContentLoaded will be fired after the scripts are parsed.

*Edit* I don't know how to mark the question as duplicate but I'm pretty sure the anwser is here already: [Defer attribute and onload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753567/defer-attribute-and-onload-event)

Comment: That is not always the case. If an `async` script was cached or quick to fetch, it would have paused `HTML` parsing while it executes, and `DOMContentLoaded` would have been fired after the script got parsed. Therefore it depends.