# queryselector does work in console but doesn't work in .js file

Tags: javascript, debugging

I wanted to add a paragraph element in a html file, and i succeeded. But, I just wanted to try in another way.
And i found a way which add the p element in a page.

This code is from stackoverflow.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
var para = document.createElement('p');
para.innerHTML = '';
document.body.appendChild(para);
};
</script>
```

By using this internal script, successfully added p element.

And i added external script with defer attribute, and inside that, entered these code.

`const para = document.querySelector('p');
para.textContent = 'hi';`

but **it doesn't work**. in debugging tool, it says "Cannot set property 'textContent' of null".

So, I checked **in console,**

`const check = document.body.querySelector('p');
check.textContent = 'hi';`

it **does work** very well..

I just thought

```
when I load my HTML,   
1st : load internal js file - make <p>. 2nd : parse whole HTML codes.   
3rd : load external js file - manipulate <p>. and it will work well.
```

***So, these are my questions.***

1. Why 'para' constant doesn't be made in .js file?
2. what is the difference with console running and source file running in this case?

Comment: perhaps the code ```document.querySelector('p')``` is being executed before the actual paragraph has been mounted to the dom. when you run from console, it is probably after the mount.

Comment: @Tal - OP clearly said that `defer` was used on script tag for the external file.

Comment: This is an order of operation problem. Both scripts are "deferred"...the in-line script is deferred by using `window.onload` attribute while the external file is deferred using `defer` so the external file is executing prior to the in-line script. Move your in-line script into your JS file and solve the problem.

Comment: @RandyCasburn you are correct, but still, the code is inside an ```onload```, which is after the defered load time see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753567/defer-attribute-and-onload-event)

Comment: Yes, a better comment than the first. And better than mine that says the same thing.

Comment: so, this was because of window.onload loading timing.
first, parse a html file
second, load a in-line script (loaded like defer attribute because of 'window.onload')
third, load a external script.
Thank you sooo much haha

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple external resources to generate markup. Try this:

```
const element = window.parent.document.querySelector(selector);
```