# How to delay an script on page load?

Tags: javascript, delay, pageload, webflow

I need to delay my auto slider during page load. I need to help bc I’m not into JS that much.
Can someone help me?

```
<script>
   // User Settings
    var transitionDuration = 1000; // set this to your "Slider Settings > Duration" in milliseconds
  var slideInterval = 5000; // The interval at which the slider should change in milliseconds
  var nextButton = '.next-button'; // The class name of your slider's "Next" button

    // Automatic Timed Slider
  var interval;
    
  $(window).on('load', function(){
    autoplay(slideInterval);
  });
  
    $(nextButton).on('click', function(){
    var button = this;
    $(button).css('pointer-events', 'none');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(button).css('pointer-events', 'auto')
    }, transitionDuration);
    autoplay();
  });
  
  function autoplay(init){
    clearInterval(interval);
    if (init){
        interval = setInterval(function(){
        $(nextButton).click();
        }, slideInterval);
    } else {
      interval = setInterval(function(){
        $(nextButton).click();
      }, slideInterval + transitionDuration);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Maybe with something likes this? But I don't know the right place.

```
setTimeout(function(){
      //deferred onload
    }, 2000);
```

Thank you!

Comment: It seems answers here what you're looking for [Defer attribute and onload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753567/defer-attribute-and-onload-event)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I believe its better not use such a delay, still you won't really know, on client side, if the page is tha same after X seconds as it's for you.

**Different people, with different computers, get different results.**

**Its better to check whenever the change you want to take place happened every 1-2 seconds with an interval.**

**If change have taken place then you can execute your script and stop the interval.**

---

**Some action :**

*For example, lets say that after 2-3 seconds, we expect a div to appear.*

We can check if our div exists by **select all elements with same class** / id and by using **length** count *how many exists*. If its 0, means that it doesnt exist.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.-img._glyph').length //=1
document.querySelectorAll('.-img._glyphSADCASDC').length //=0
```

Now with **setInterval** and **clearInterval**, we are going to keep checking.

We will check until our condition is true, then stop our interval loop.

```
myInterval = setInterval(()=>{
        console.log('myInterval interval called...');
    if ( document.querySelectorAll('.-img._glyphSASA').length > 0 ) {
            //YOUR CODE HERE

            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: you can be more specific about what change you expect after those 3 seconds so I can help. A link or fiddle would be great to. Have fun !

Answer (score -1):

```js
const myTimeout = setTimeout(myGreeting, 3000);

function myGreeting() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Happy Birthday!"
}
```

```html
<p>Wait 3 seconds...</p>

<h2 id="demo"></h2>
```