# Negate inconsistent (and late) page rendering in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, asynchronous, safari

### The situation

I have been attempting to create a *react* application. The index page that is loaded first contains a basic CSS and HTML loading animation and then the external scripts and CSS in a blocking order right before `</body>`, with the last script removing the loader animation and showing the page.

The intended purpose of this is to load a very small page (`2KB` in total) containing a loading animation and then load the `8MB` of scripts, stylesheets and images, creating a more seamless user experience.

[image]

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    [loader css]
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="loader">...</div>

    <script src="..."></script>
    <script src="..."></script>
    <link href="..." type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script> [remove #loader] </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### The problem

This works great in Chrome, as it immediately renders the page (loading animation) and then the external dependencies. But because [safari has weird, inconsistent, and ostensibly non-deterministic loading practices](http://www.betalogue.com/2007/09/18/safari-unpredictable-delay-before-rendering-starts/):

> Safari starts loading the contents of the new web page, but does not start rendering it until it has loaded a sufficient amount of information.

**this approach does not work**; it'll just show the address bar loading indicator (for the dependencies above the closing `body` tag) and a blank page instead of rendering the HTML straight away.

---

If anybody has a solution that:

- won't change the order in which things are loaded on the page
- works on as many browsers as possible
- is safe from cross-site scripting vulnerabilities

that would be enormously appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you certain that 9-year-old article still applies?

Comment: To an extent, yes. Maybe the exact technology doesn't still apply but the behaviour can be replicated today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is that browsers cannot be certain your JavaScript is safe to skip over until it's been loaded, parsed, and executed. If you were to add the `defer` attribute to your scripts the page will load and display without waiting for the assets to download - but the removal of the loader will also execute without waiting.

Consider a combination of adding `defer` to the external scripts and making the loader removal script itself an external `defer` script. [According to some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10731231/2833161) `defer` scripts are supposed to execute in the order they were specified. (Also take note of the references to `async` and [DOMContentLoaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/2833161) on that comment.)

React.js might also provide come callbacks that could be used more reliably than DOMContentReady.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! As far as I can tell, I don't need the browser to be certain the JavaScript is safe to skip over. I just need to load the scripts/stylesheets in such a way that safari displays the rendered DOM before blocking and showing a white screen while it downloads the scripts/stylesheets.

Comment: I think deferring the load will make Safari render the page instead of blocking - it's about Safari being sure it's safe to skip over, not you as the developer. Is it easy to test?

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so long to accept this, I haven't worked on this project in a while. I'm using this with a bundled `vuejs` application. Displaying the loader in the `<div id="app"> ... loader ... </div>` and then re-rendering vue over the top once loaded works great using the `async` attribute. I only load one file now so execution order is no longer a problem. Still a weird issue, but this seems to be the only viable workaround for the time being.