# Should I use defer on script which are already at just before the bottom body tag?

Tags: javascript, html, http, deferred

This question has always bothered me every time I put my js files at the bottom of the page. if I put all js files at the bottom before the closing `body` tag then I think that the browser will first download all the html and style sheets then it will parse the html and css and at last it will send requests for js files. So,

- Would using `defer` on js files which are already at the bottom make any difference?
- Are non deferred scripts at the end just before body tag render blocking?

Another question I have is if I put all js file in the head and use `defer` on them. Would this be equivalent to placing all js files at the bottom? Would seeing js with defer in `head` the browser make request to the server and then continue downloading rest of html file or will it make request to server only after downloading all html and css?

As far as I know `async` is equivalent to `defer` and the only difference is the js will be executed when downloaded without respecting the order of files. So,

- Would using `async` on js files which are already at the bottom make any difference except from the order in which they are executed?

Comment: yes, defer is basically akin to putting tags at the end of the body.

Answer (score 15):

Looking through the [HTML 5.2 spec](https://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-scripting.html#element-attrdef-script-async) for Scripting, one finds [this illustration](https://w3c.github.io/html/images/asyncdefer.svg) W3C uses.

What we see here is that using `defer` fetches the script while the HTML is being parsed, but waits until parsing is concluded before executing.

`async`, on the other hand, fetches alongside parsing, and once the fetch is complete, HTML rendering is paused to execute the script.

Since HTML execution is synchronous, one can assume that using `defer` on scripts placed just before `</head>` would be almost like placing them just before `</body>`.

However, as [Chris Moschini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10731231/6232278) states, I would not trust `defer`. I feel [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work) StackOverflow answer as a whole would better explain how `defer` affects loading JavaScripts.

Comment: But many sites like gtmatrix give less score if I don't use defer. I think now a days modern browsers would have got `defer` implemented correctly.

Comment: Maybe so. Taking that into consideration then, using `defer` on scripts in the `<head>` or mixed within content would keep them blocking the render process, and in effect, speed up page render time. However, it will affect execution time, which would throw off scripts just above `</body>`.

Comment: I meant to mention [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) in the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

The defer attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing.

Note: The defer attribute is only for external scripts (should only be used if the src attribute is present).

Comment: Well no. It doesn't execute script after _page_ is parsed. It executes script after html document(DOM) is parsed and before `DOMContentLoaded` is fired, as per MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script Do you have any other reference?

Comment: i find this from https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp you should check it.

Comment: I have found MDN wrong one or two time times only but w3schools -- many time. So I think MDN is more trustworthy than w3school.

Answer (score 0):

This post I found explains it well: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/

Ideally, the best practice is to have <script defer... in . If you use a CDN, for example, this allows the script to be downloaded while the HTML is being parsed.