# Unable to call Jquery-UI javascript files in async mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asynchronous

I want to call the javascript files in async/defer mode as it is good practice. But when I tried the same with jQuery/jQuery-UI js it is not working anymore?

Is there anything wrong with my code? If so please correct me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <!--script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" async></script-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"  type="text/javascript" async></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo" style="border: 1px solid black; width:400px; height:300px;"  class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Hello Dragger</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#demo").draggable();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I am getting the exception "*(index):15 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)*" because I am using the async/defer thing. But I am already using document.ready to get rid of this exception.

It was only able to run with setTimeout but it's not the cleaner approach. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: it is working with these two version   https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js and https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: `defer` means the script won't execute until *after* the DOM is complete. This "obviously" means it (`$` from jQuery) won't be ready by the time the inline script is run. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5251182/2864740 for a brief summary. The `defer`'d scripts will still be run in script order relative to each other - so if the inline JavaScript is put in an external file loaded later it'll "just start working".

Comment: Also, `defer` and `async` do complete different things and it is confusing to say `async/defer` when it is not. And finally (for now), this same error will exist without  jQuery-UI as the problem is with `$(document)`..

Comment: @GraveyardQueen I tried with the mentioned js but still same error. 
Chrome version - 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)
Safari - 10.0

Comment: the problem is with the defer in the script tag if you remove that it will work with your current code itself

Comment: @GraveyardQueen it will surely work as browser will firstly create the all the variables then rest page will create hence it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

As I want to load the DOM faster so I used async/defer. But $ jquery variable was not defined because jquery library is not loaded yet. So in order to handle this I simply inserted my jquery code in window.onload

```js
window.onload = function () {
 $(function () {$("#demo").draggable(); 
     }); 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"  type="text/javascript" async></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo" style="border: 1px solid black; width:400px; height:100px;">
        <p>Hello Dragger</p>
    </div>
    <script src="../static/js/external.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this might helped others(newbie like me).

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is, you are load the scripts asynchronously. So the scripts takes some time to load into the webpage (maybe small mile-seconds).

Before that time `$(document).ready` will be called, but at that time jquery scripts not loaded in the page.

To handle this case you can use any module loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), also the good this is jquery-ui already supported AMD module loader.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"  type="text/javascript" defer></script>-->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.2/require.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo" style="border: 1px solid black; width:400px; height:300px;"  class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Hello Dragger</p>
    </div>
    <script>

        requirejs.config({
            paths: {
                "jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4",
                "jquery-ui": "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui"
            }
        });

        require(["jquery-ui"], function () {

            $("#demo").draggable();

        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but don't you think that now again we have to wait for require.js but we want to decrease the Dom load time.

Comment: Yes, but loading requireJS doesn't take much more time since it was 6kb only (gzip). However you need any module loader to perform the asyn operation, which requirejs will do. As per your below answer it is not a reliable one, since you request 3 scripts simultaneously (async). Suppose the external script first came, at that time it will break. Also for an application point of view that is not safe.

One more thing, requirejs will handle the module dependency (i.e, the external script will wait until its dependency jquery will load), so i hope it is more convenient for async process.