# Highlight current page in menu using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This following code worked fine. But the teacher asked me to explain "if(menu!==null)" and I couldn't explain it. He said it was mandatory, but I deleted it and it still worked. This is an example of Home page.

```js
function setBold() {
  var menu = document.getElementById('page').getAttribute("data-page");
  if (menu !== null) {
    document.getElementById(menu).className = "active";
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="setBold()" id="page" data-page="Home">
  <div class="menu">
    <a id="Home" href="">Home</a>
    <a id="About" href="">About My Cakes</a>
    <a id="Find" href="">Find Maria's Coffe</a>
  </div>

  <body>
```

Comment: I think you should decide what needs to happen when `menu == null`, one option is to set `home page` to `active`.

Answer (score 0):

If your teacher said `if(menu!==null)` is mandatory.
Then the code will do something with **data-page** attribute later.(remove/add)

Let's say if **data-page** attribute will be removed later, and you don't have this if condition, `document.getElementById(menu).className = "active";` will cause an error because you are trying to add a class to null.

Comment: The results are the same if I remove **data-page** of Home page. The script doesn't run then. It's like `if(menu!=null)` is there for nothing

Comment: You removed **data-page** attribute and if condition,The code still running without an error after setBold() is fried?

Answer (score 0):

This `if(menu!==null)` condition is added because of the following reasons-:

1. There can be a situation when there is no `data-page` in `body`.
2. The script may run before the body is rendered, this can happen if we don't use `defer` attribute in `<script>` tag.

[How exactly does <script defer="defer"> work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work)

Comment: If there is no `data-page` in `body` then `document.getElementById(menu).className = "active";` doesn't compile. So `if(menu!==null)` becomes redundance.