# Script with defer prevents loading of Angular App

Tags: html, angular, asynchronous, deferred

I have an Angular app which depends on a script on a server, that isn't always stable. So sometimes it takes some time to get loaded. Therefore I added a `defer`-attribute on it. But the App waits until the download of the deferred script is finished.

Based on my research the Angular App should render before the `DOMContentLoaded`. I even tried it with a new Angular App with the same result. I deferred the loading of the `defer.js` by 10 sec.
The HTML of the Angular App looks like the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <script src="http://localhost:8080/defer.js" defer></script>

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Here the result in the Browser]

The following HTML gets loaded in the Browser. On the Angular Scripts aren't any `defer`, so they should be executed IMO.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <script src="http://localhost:8080/defer.js" defer=""></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
        <script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="styles.js" defer></script>
        <script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

(I use the Chrome Browser Plugin 'URL Throttler' to emulate it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
Scripts with `type="module"` are deferred by default. Therefore the browser blocks the execution to it until the previous `defer`-scripts are executed

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250412/how-exactly-does-script-defer-defer-work?rq=2) for the difference between async/defer but it seems that your problem could be resolved by adding async.

> In certain situations some browsers have a bug that causes defer
> scripts to run out of order. Some browsers delay the DOMContentLoaded
> event until after the defer scripts have loaded, and some don't. Some
> browsers obey defer on  elements with inline code and without
> a src attribute, and some ignore it.