# Get contents of another site's element using only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, greasemonkey

I'm making a userscript that requires finding a word related to another word. I found [a site](http://semantic-link.com/) where I can go to http://semantic-link.com/#/stack, and there will be a list of words related to `stack` in the format of:

```
<!-- various stuffs here, e.g. <head>, a <div>, another <div>, start of <body> -->

    <div id="word0" class="word" onclick="updateTitle("stacks");" style="opacity: 1;">
        stacks
    </div>
    <div id="word1" class="word" onclick="updateTitle("flue");" style="opacity: 1;">
        flue
    </div>
    <div id="word2" class="word" onclick="updateTitle("popped");" style="opacity: 1;">
        popped
    </div>
    <div id="word3" class="word" onclick="updateTitle("overflow");" style="opacity: 1;">
        overflow
    </div>
```

In this case, I would want to just get the string `stacks` from that page. All of the solutions I have found don't work because they:

- need a custom page,
- use PHP, or
- use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), or [`$('something').load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which are limited to the domain they are executed in.

Is there any way I can get the contents of the `#word0` element as a string, using only JavaScript? Alternatively, is there another way to find a word related to another word?

Comment: if you use iframe i think yes you can.

Comment: What about a scriptlet/bookmarklet?  What do you plan on using the results for?  Pretty sure doing this is a violation of cross-site scripting which is why you would have to use those tools. (And why ajax won't work)

Comment: I don't think that this would be possible with JavaScript, but you could use PHP's (if that is your server-side language) http://us2.php.net/file_get_contents

Comment: @JayBlanchard No, it needs to be JavaScript.

Comment: @zero298 I was going to send the word as a message in an SE chat room.

Comment: @ProllyGeek No, you can't [Get DOM content of cross-domain iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6170925/691711)

Comment: If you do not own the page or have the option of AJAX then you cannot get the content of a remote page using JavaScript alone.

Comment: See if there is a restful API or a way to do some JSONP magic or maybe even a CORS if you are lucky.

Comment: @ProllyGeek the same-origin policy does. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: you could certainly ask [the owner](http://mpacula.com/) of semantic-link for a RESTful API that you could call

Comment: You **CAN** do this using the techniques from ["How to get an AJAX get-request to wait for the page to be rendered before returning a response?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11489451/331508).  Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey do cross-domain mashups all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just get the JSON he is getting? Correct me if I'm wrong but you are only after related words but not what a user is clicking?

```
$.get("http://semantic-link.com/related.php?word="+word);
```

EDIT: try this:

```
$.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fsemantic-link.com%2Frelated.php%3Fword%3Dword'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=",function(data){
alert(data.query.results.json.json[0].v);
});
```

Comment: Because that call doesn't work across different domains in JavaScript.

Comment: @AdrianWragg, that call works fine, and to that domain, from a userscript, if `$.get` is replaced by `GM_xmlhttpRequest`.

Comment: You are right. It does not have necessary headers. Added YQL version

Answer (score 6):

You state in your question that:

> `$.ajax()`, `$.get()`, or `$('something').load()` ... are limited to the domain they are executed in.

This appears to point the finger at jQuery. Actually, the limitation is with Javascript in the browser itself, and is down to a particular security aspect called [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy):

> The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site – a combination of scheme, hostname, and port number – to access each other's DOM with no specific restrictions, but prevents access to DOM on different sites

In essence, what you are trying to do is not possible, unless the remote server has [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) enabled to allow queries from your server to call across to it. As you are not in control of the remote server, I doubt this is set up.

Comment: Actually, userscripts have APIs, like `GM_xmlhttpRequest` to do cross-domain AJAX.  That is not the main problem here anyway, as the target page is AJAX driven -- which requires more of a workaround.

Comment: @BrockAdams Just to clarify, am I right in saying that any user script would require the user to install a third-party plugin or script first (which would probably trigger security warnings)?

Comment: No. Chrome and Opera support this natively.  But use the Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey and/or Scriptish extensions; they are better. As for security and privacy: their code's openly viewable and/or open-source and has a solid track record. Frankly, those extensions are less risk than installing Chrome or Firefox in the first place.

Comment: @BrockAdams Sorry, but you seem to be saying that *by default* Chrome and Opera allow cross-domain scripting without the user installing any plugins or scripts into the browser itself. It's obviously an area that you know better than I do, so I think our wires have been crossed somewhere here.

Comment: No, I'm saying that by *default* Those browsers allow cross-domain scripting, *from a userscript*, without the user installing any plugins or extensions.  The OP stated and implied that he was "making a userscript", so installing a userscript is a given.

Comment: @BrockAdams You're right; I was distracted by the OP coming across cross-domain issues, which (if s/he *was* actually writing a userscript) should not have been an issue. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Cross domain is still an issue for *jQuery* AJAX, even from a userscript. (jQuery does not use the privileged `GM_xmlhttpRequest` function)  So, that part's still right.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible with just javascript due to the same-origin policy. There has to be some server-side intervention to retrieve the html, whether that be through a 3rd party service (such as YQL) or your own php(or otherwise) script.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is quite feasible and quite simple to accomplish.

First you must notice that when you query for any word in that website it'll make an "ajax" call behind the scenes, like for example: http://semantic-link.com/related.php?word=shrewd. Being aware of that URL is the trick.

And please notice that it brings you a JSON format as response. So all you need to do with now is to parse it. Just replace the word in the URL in the example above by the one you want to use and you're done. ;)

Comment: That works on the site itself because they are on the same domain. The functionality would be different when a call is made from a different domain, due to the cross-domain issues mentioned.

Comment: Yeah. It still must be done from back-end. But it's better to know there is a JSON friendly URL for it in advance.

Comment: That is a good point, and worth knowing if the original questioner does decide to go down that route instead of implementing a pure JS solution.

Comment: Calling that URL works perfectly fine from a userscript using `GM_xmlhttpRequest`.  It's pure JS (standard userscript API) and no back-end required.