# How can I use Greasemonkey to get information from an other AJAX site?

Tags: jquery, ajax, greasemonkey

I want to use Greasemonkey to display more information at the site menu.
the new information should show how many orders/items are behind the menuelinks.

e.g.
New Orders (1)
Proofed Orders (20)

I tried this code:

```
//NEW
var pageInhalt = getTheImportant('http://example.com/orders.php?s=NEW&');
if (pageInhalt.indexOf('from ') > 0) {
   var amount = pageInhalt.substring( pageInhalt.indexOf('from ')+4,  pageInhalt.indexOf('</td>', pageInhalt.indexOf('from ')+5));
   $( "#div01" ).find( "li:contains('NEW')" ).append(' (' + amount + ') ');
}
else { $( "#div01" ).find( "li:contains('NEW')" ).append(' (0) '); }

function getTheImportant(url) {
  var result;

  $.ajax({
      type:    "GET",
      url:     url,
      async:   false,
      success: function(data) {
        result = data;
      }
  });

  return result;
}
```

But now the source has changed from a static table to a dynamic table.
My problem is that the dynamic part will load the information I need - the amount of orders/items.

so my  `$.ajax` isn't working anymore.

I know that I can use `waitForKeyElements` and I also use this succsessfull with an other script but without `$.ajax` call.
How can I tell `$.ajax` to wait for a key element?

---

Rolled in from OP's response, below:

The site with the table is behind a login. But I can show an example which looks similar:
          [datatables.net/examples/styling/jqueryUI.html](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/jqueryUI.html)

There you can see 'Showing 31 to 40 of 57 entries'.
The number 57 would be the information I need.

One this page with the table I use Greasemonkey in this way:

```
function makeAction (jNode) {
   //find the number of entries an do somthing with the result
   $(this).find....
}

waitForKeyElements (".odd", makeAction);
```

But I need a little bit help how I can get this information by a link (the menuelink) using AJAX.
If I use AJAX I will get only the source code without the dynamic part - the Table. So my conclusion was I should use `waitForKeyElements` with AJAX?

Comment: It's now clear that this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486256/how-to-get-an-ajax-get-request-to-wait-for-the-page-to-be-rendered-before-return

Comment: Thanks a lot Brock Adams this will help me!