# How to transfer Values(items) from one Netsuit business system form to another Netsuit form automatically?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, tampermonkey, data-transfer

Currently, I have to fill out 2 of the same forms with the same language & part numbers on the Web Based business system "Netsuit" made by Oracle (extremely annoying & waste of time). I need to use a software/code system to read one form entry and duplicate it to the other automatically, just still feeling out the best way to do this and get it to transfer/skim properly.

This is between 2 sister companies, each value(Part) has a different part number linked to them, but internally they cannot be linked due to reporting purposes and which company sales what.

One company starts with 100XXX-XX numbers and the other starts with 300XXX-XX numbers for the parts. Again, they are basically the same Parts.

Not sure if Tampermonkey or java will be able to do this properly as I don't even know where to start.

Any recommendations or walkthough on the best way to do this would be awesome, I know it might be a little hard since its 2 different item systems.
Maybe just pull the description of the items since they will be almost the same?

Comment: Tampermonkey can do this with a variation of [these techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11489451), but we're not going to code it blind, and from scratch, for you.  The question needs at a minimum, either a [mcve] or links to publicly accessible web pages that exhibit the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a user event script on the first company and RESTlet on the second one.

The user event script on the first company will create a JSON object of the item that is being created and pre-process the changes in the part number(or any other changes that is required) for the second company and send it to the second company's RESTlet. The RESTlet will now then create the item for the second company.

By using this approach you don't need any 3rd party application to deal with.