# How to hide a section in dynamics crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

So I have a form with 3 sections. I want a functionality where Section 1 gets filled than section 2 shows up and so on.

I know the basic code of JavaScript but I don't know where to use it or how to invoke it. 
I have made a web resource with SHOW and HIDE functions, now how do I invoke them.

I am currently working the idea of using JAVA SCRIPT to hide the sections and show the latter sections when the former gets filled up. Here is my code.

```
function Hide()
{ Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("yourtabname").sections.get("your section name").setVisible(false); } 
function Show()
{ Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("yourtabname").sections.get("your section name").setVisible(true); }
```

Now I am aware that `Show()` will get attached to the last field of section 1 of the form, but what about the `Hide()` function? where will I invoke it?

Comment: please edit your question instead adding the code inside a comment

Comment: So you're saying that you want to hide sections 2 and 3 at first? Try putting it in the load event of the document http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880307/trigger-event-on-body-load-complete-js-jquery

Comment: make all 3 sections invisible on the form. in onload() make section 1 visible. then you'll have to mess around with the onchange events of the fields in section 1 to determine if section 2 should be visible or not. same for section 3 based on section 2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly i guess it's a personal preference however I would have a "validate" function and ensure you have all the information you need before hiding the first section (what happens if they enter the last field first for instance?)

Then I would just do something like the following and call it on all fields in the section:

```
function SectionOneField_OnChange()
{
    if (IsSectionOneValid())
    {
         Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("NextTab").sections.get("NextSection").controls.get(0).setFocus();
         Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("FirstTab").sections.get("SectionOne").setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Side note : As with most CRM javascript this probably isn't Microsoft supported :-)

Comment: thank you guys for all the answers/suggestions. Where can I find the Onload event on the form to put the script there?
Right now I can only find Onchange() event when i try to put it on the last field of section 1

Comment: @user2609743 To get the form events (there is OnLoad and OnSave) click on "Form Properties" in the CRM Ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this while looking for code for something similar. Don't think it's *exactly* what you want but it may help!

http://www.magnetismsolutions.co.nz/blog/11-06-28/Show_a_Tab_Based_on_a_Radio_Button_Dynamics_CRM_2011.aspx

The guy has a few other useful articles on Dynamics CRM 2011 too.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this code for hiding/show tab:

Show:

```
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("TabName").setVisible(true);
```

Hide:

```
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("TabName").setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Section is different from Tab.